# UILabel and superscript

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have two strings:

- a variable length piece of text
- another string with numbers that
  point to a reference

In my view, the first piece of text is displayed in a UILabel, I adjust the size of the label to accomodate the size of the text. This means I **cannot** just place another UILabel on the screen, at least not without repositioning it...somehow.

I need to be able to put the second piece of text so it appears to be at the end of the sentence - and **superscripted**

I really have no idea how to achieve this!

Answer (score 7):

My rather dodgy solution was to enter unicode characters for the superscripted numbers.

Not a great solution but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use two different UILabels. A better solution might be to draw both strings using -drawInRect:withFont: in a custom view's -drawRect: method.

Comment: How would I position them correctly though? The control in question can have varied length text so positioning the references at one point wont work

Comment: Ah, if there's dynamic text, then you'll need to go the drawing route.

Comment: You could then use -sizeWithFont: to figure out how large your string will be when drawn, and place the second string in an appropriate location.